# Game theory problem involving bitwise XOR

Tags: c++, game-theory

I participated in a DIV 2 contest on codeforces but was unable to solve [this](https://codeforces.com/contest/1384/problem/D) problem.

I understand what the most significant bit means, but the way in which it has been used in the [solution](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/80562) confuses me. I just need help with the logic behind the solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

So first, let's understand what actually wins the game.

Since at the end, they are comparing the score, and the one with higher score wins, so the only thing that matter is the most significant bit of each ones' score.

Since the way to gain score is by taking numbers from the given array, so the only thing that matters is the most significant bit of each numbers from the array. Only both player will get the same score from the most significant bit, you would need to test the next bit.

> Let x be the number of ones and y be the numbers of zeros in the most significant bit of the numbers:
>
> if x is even, whatever decision players take, both will end with the same score in that bit, so go to the next bit (if it doesn't exist the game ends in a draw). Indeed, the parity of the result of both players will be the same, since x is even.

To make the question simple, I will assume all the numbers contained in the array are either 1 or 0. Imagine you have 4 numbers in the array, [1, 1, 1, 1]. If the both player would have to xor 1 twice. So both of them get (0 xor 1) xor 1 = 0.

In fact, as long the numbers of 1 are even, they would always tie, because both of them will xor same amount of 1. On the other hand, xor 0 doesn't change their score.

So we can get: **x mod 2 = 0 gives tie**

---

Now let's think about how player 1 would win or lose. The most simple case, if there's [1, (0)...], or only one 1's, and whatever numbers of 0, player 1 win.

Here we can get **if x = 1, p1 wins**

Then how can you make player 1 lose? As long there's a 1 in the array, player 1 can take it. So to make him lose, player 1 has to take another 1, and player 2 also need to take a 1. Which means, you would require at least three 1's to make player 1 lose.

Here we can get **if x = 3, p1 may lose**

But how do you ensure that player 1 will take that extra 1? We have to make sure player 1 is the last player to pick, so he has no choice but to pick it. To do that, we will have even numbers of 0. By doing that, p2 can always copy what p1 has done, except taking that extra 1.

Let's say we had [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]. Then they would be doing:

P1: 1, 0, 1

P2: 1, 0,

 or:

P1: 0, 1, 1

P2: 0, 1,

Now we can get **if x = 3, y mod 2 = 0, p1 lose**

Now lets see if we can generalize this part, let's say we have x = 5. Now, no matter whay p2 does, p1 can always ensure odd numbers of 1, so he will always win.

Similarly, if we have x = 7, we would have a case just the same as x = 3. If we have even numbers of 0, p2 can always make p1 get even number's of 1.

Now we get:

**if x mod 2 = 0, they tie**

**if x mod 4 = 1, p1 wins** and

**if x mod 4 = 3, y mod 2 = 1, p1 wins** and

**if x mod 4 = 3, y mod 2 = 0, p1 lose**, which is basically what they had for the solution.